# AEM 6.1: Renditions for an Asset within another Asset

Tags: java, aem, jcr, dam

I am using AEM 6.1 I create an asset inside another asset within the DAM. Say an asset containing a PDF file, inside another asset containing an HTML file. Now, normally when I make a PDF asset go through a Workflow, there is a step in the Workflow that will automatically generate thumbnails from the asset (with default sizes, defined by AEM). But what if the PDF asset is a child to the HTML asset, will I still automatically get renditions from it?

In other words, I now I can get these relationships, the first through regular asset creation and the second through a workflow.

HTML Asset->PDF Asset (as child node)

PDF Asset->Renditions (as child node)

But can I get this relationship through a workflow:

HTML Asset->PDF Asset (as child node)->Renditions (as child node)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the steps how you have created a sub asset to a an asset in DAM.?

Comment: I just made it to work so I guess I can close the question. I just created a child asset as a child node of the parent asset with AssetManager by giving the path. The workflow does, indeed, produce renditions for child assets as well. :D